# INotifyPropertyChanged and static variables

Tags: c#, xaml

I need to display a value in my window that is changing when a function is called.
Doing some reading I understand that I need to implement the INotifyPropertyChanged to do so.

My problem is that I need the variable that holds that value to be static so that it can be altered by other functions.

Here is my implementation:

```
class Shown : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int _Count;
    public int Count
    {
        get { return _Count; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _Count)
            {
                _Count = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Count");
            }
        }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged(string propName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
    }
}
```

Here is what I would like to be possible with the interface implemented:

```
Shown.Count += SomeVariable;
```

Then the altered value to refresh in the TextBlock that is binded to.

I know my description of the issue is... wanting, but I am at a loss myself.

Comment: Where you defined it as static?

Comment: The original class before implementation was: class Shown { public static int Count}

Comment: Now you cannot access `Shown.Count` you required an instance make them as static

Comment: Did solve exactly the same problem, yesterday.  I am on mobile so no code for now. But create a static class and have a static property in it as Shown type.In the getter check if the instance already exist then return that. If it's null then return a new instance. Now set the data context using the static class's property.

Comment: Kinda lost you after "In the getter check", what should I add in my {get}?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered, rather than that property being statically available, to have an instance of the Shown class statically available? This would allow you to access the Count property across the entire application, assuming you only need one instance of Shown.